# What is the most effecient way to check if a variable isset and to assign its value or set a default value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a long multidimensional array value that may or may not be present.

What is the most efficient way to check for it being set, to use its value, or otherwise use an alternate value, **without repeating the reference to the multidimensional array**?

Here you can see the long array is referenced twice, can that be avoided?

```
$source = null;
$default = 'something';
if(isset($request['controller']['options']['data']['source'])) {
    $source = $request['controller']['options']['data']['source'];
} else {
    $source = $default;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check the index using array_key_exists & put it in a variable, in that way you could avoid the multi-dimesion reference.

Comment: cant you do this `$mulit_dim_array = $request['controller']['options']['data']['source'];` and use it in both references?

Comment: @noobie-php I get an error if $request['controller']['options']['data']['source']; does not exist. Its possible only $request['controller'] exists and the options array is not present.

Comment: try `$mulit_dim_array = isset($request['controller']['options']['data']['source']);`

Comment: @noobie-php that sets $mulit_dim_array to true or false (the output of isset)

Comment: @sterling: agreed , thanks for correction

Comment: @MaK do you want to share your solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
$source = null;
$default = 'something';
if(isset($request['controller']['options']['data']['source']) && $request['controller']['options']['data']['source']) {
    $source = $request['controller']['options']['data']['source'];
} else {
    $source = $default;
}
```

Comment: I am looking to avoid repeating the full multidimensional array reference.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is another way if you dont wanna do as i told in comment or if you wanna avoid what you are doing.

```
(isset($request['controller']['options']['data']['source'])) ? $source = $request['controller']['options']['data']['source']
        : ($source = $default);
```

Comment: That uses the reference to the multi-dimensional array twice, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$your_variable = $request['controller']['options']['data']['source'];
```

will lead to a warning if any of the keys is not existing. So will not work. I think the best way is to create a helper method that does the trick

```
<?php
/**
 * Retrieve value from a multi dimensional array or default if key not exists
 *
 * @param array $input
 * @param array $key_list
 * @param mixed $default
 * @return mixed
 */
function mda_helper(array $input, array $key_list, $default) {
    foreach ($key_list as $key) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $input)) {
            return $default;
        }

        $input = $input[$key];
    }

    return $input;
}

$request = [
    'controller' => [
        'options' => [
            'data' => [
                //'source' => 'foo'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$default = 'something';

$source = mda_helper($request, ['controller', 'options', 'data', 'source'], $default);
```

Comment: This is an elegant answer but, if key matching/existence not to be accounted then its really costly.

Comment: That is true, putting 100.000 repeats for each solution, the original post is 10x faster: 0.080080032348633 ms vs. 0.91248297691345 ms

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with PHP 7, use the ["null coalesce" (a.k.a. "isset ternary") operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary):

`$source = ($request['controller']['options']['data']['source'] ?? $default)`

Answer (score -1):

```
  $source = null;
    $default = 'something';
    if(isset($request['controller']['options']['data']['source']) && !empty($request['controller']['options']['data']['source'])) {
        $source = $request['controller']['options']['data']['source'];
    } else {
        $source = $default;
    }
```

Comment: This throws and error if the options array does not exist:
$your_variable = $request['controller']['options']['data']['source'];